# python- helper list for sys.argv CLI argument

Tags: python, argparse, argv, sys

I have to read a CLI argument for my python script and then pass that input argument by the user to a method. I want to provide user with a list of valid arguments that she can enter, sort of when you run the script with an invalid argument or with no argument passed- it shows you that you can only enter these arguments.

I know we can achieve this with argparse module, but argparse in my case will be an overkill- since I just want to pass whatever (valid)argument the user gave to a method. How should I achieve this?

```
parser.add_argument('--system-status', '-st', metavar='<host>', type=str)
if args.system-status:
    method(args.system-status)
```

And the same stuff repeated for 5 other variables?

Comment: argparse is not a heavy tool, and takes just 2 lines to setup for 1 argument, and comes as a part of standard lib so no dependencies. Does not sound like an overkill at all

Comment: @Andrei, I have 6 arguments, so it'll need 6 lines for each and then to pass that argument again to the method, a if condition for each argument? eg- if I have a variable named "myvaribale1", I'll need to do if args.myvariable: method(args.myvariable) and the same stuff for the other 5 variables. It just seems like a lot of repetition

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Use argparse, especially if you don't know how to achieve it otherwise. And add what you have so far, or what kind of args you're talking about. We have little to go by now. [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ThePjot Added an example.

Comment: You'll need 6 checks anyway, how else do you expect to do the checks otherwise? :) Argparse has the benefit of making the 'invalid arguments' and 'possible arguments' helper much easier.

Comment: `argparse` is primarily a parser, a way of determining what your user wants.  Execution is something you do after parsing.  There are other (third-party) packages that attempt to streamline some of that.  The other thing the `argparse` provides is a standardized help/usage, and error messages.  You've already customized the help with the `metavar` parameter.

Comment: You can parse the `sys.argv` list yourself.  But unless you are just looking for a couple of strings, and no flags like `-st`, using one of the parsing packages will make the job easier.

Comment: You could certainly write one or more utility functions that handle the repetitive parts of `add_argument` and post-parsing.  But it's probably easier to start off explicitly repeating the stuff (you know how to copy-n-paste?), and later, when you see a pattern, repackage things.

Answer (score 0):

The argparse lib is the way to go, if you dont want to check for each parameter you could use something like this:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo')
parser.add_argument('--bar')
parser.add_argument('--baz')
args = parser.parse_args()

def f(foo=None, bar=None, baz=None, **kwargs):
    print(foo)
    print(bar)
    print(baz)

f(**args.__dict__)
```

`**args.__dict__` will turn args in a dictionary turn it into kwargs.

If you really absolutly don't want to use argparse then sys.argv will give you the list of parameters passed to the function.